# my data is undefined in my d3.js data viz

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to build a line graph that when the user hovers over a part of the chart, a callout appears with the date, country and incidents data points. however currently all my data points show up as 'undefined'. does anyone know what's going on here?

here is my code.

```
function circleHover(chosen) {

  if (modus == "incidents") {

    d3.select("#callOut")
      .style("top", "570px")
      .style("left", "30px"); 


    d3.select("#divCountry").html('Country: ' + chosen.country);
    d3.select("#divDate").html('Date: ' + chosen.date);
    d3.select("#divIncidents").html('Incidents: ' + chosen.incidents);

    d3.select("#callOut")
    .style("visibility","visible");

  }

  if (modus == "fatalities") {

    d3.select("#callOut2")
      .style("top", "570px")
      .style("left", "30px");  

    d3.select("#divCountry2").html('Country: ' + chosen.country);
    d3.select("#divDate2").html('Date: ' + chosen.date);
    d3.select("#divFatalities2").html('Fatalities: ' + chosen.fatalities);

    d3.select("#callOut2")
    .style("visibility","visible");

  }

  if (modus == "injuries") {

    d3.select("#callOut3")
      .style("top", "570px")
      .style("left", "30px"); 

    d3.select("#divCountry3").html('Country: ' + chosen.country);
    d3.select("#divDate3").html('Date: ' + chosen.date);
    d3.select("#divInjuries3").html('Injuries: ' + chosen.injuries);

    d3.select("#callOut3")
    .style("visibility","visible");

  }

}; 




function showOne(d) {


  var margin = {top: 80, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


  var svg = d3.select("#svg").append("svg")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);

  var incidentsData = svg.append("g"); 

  incidentsData.selectAll(".incidentsData")
                .data(incidentData)
                .enter()
                .append('incidentsData')
                .attr('class', 'incidentsData');


  var fatalitiesData = svg.append("g");

  fatalitiesData.selectAll(".fatalitiesData")
                .data(fatalityData)
                .enter()
                .append('fatalitiesData')
                .attr('class', 'fatalitiesData');

  var injuriesData = svg.append("g"); 

  injuriesData.selectAll(".injuriesData")
                .data(injuryData) 
                .enter()
                .append('injuriesData')
                .attr('class', 'injuriesData'); 

  var chosen = d;
  var setOpacity = 0;

  if (modus == "incidents") {
      circleHover(chosen);
      setOpacity = 0.1;


  incidentsData.selectAll(".incidentsData")
    .filter(function (d) { return eval("d.country") != eval("chosen.country");})
    .style("fill-opacity", setOpacity);


  }

  if (modus == "fatalities") {
      circleHover(chosen);
      setOpacity = 0.1;


  fatalitiesData.selectAll(".fatalitiesData")
    .filter(function (d) { return eval("d.country") != eval("chosen.country");})
    .style("fill-opacity", setOpacity);

  }

  if (modus == "injuries") {
      circleHover(chosen);
      setOpacity = 0.1;


  injuriesData.selectAll(".injuriesData")
    .filter(function (d) { return eval("d.country") != eval("chosen.country");})
    .style("fill-opacity", setOpacity);


  }

}; 



function showAll() {


  var margin = {top: 80, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


  var svg = d3.select("#svg").append("svg")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);

  var incidentsData = svg.append("g"); 

  incidentsData.selectAll(".incidentsData")
                .data(incidentData)
                .enter()
                .append('incidentsData')
                .attr('class', 'incidentsData');

  var fatalitiesData = svg.append("g");

  fatalitiesData.selectAll(".fatalitiesData")
                .data(fatalityData)
                .enter()
                .append('fatalitiesData')
                .attr('class', 'fatalitiesData');


  var injuriesData = svg.append("g"); 

  injuriesData.selectAll(".injuriesData")
                .data(injuryData) 
                .enter()
                .append('injuriesData')
                .attr('class', 'injuriesData'); 

  if (modus == "incidents") {

  incidentsData.selectAll(".incidentsData")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.5);

  d3.select("#callOut").style("visibility","hidden");

  }

  if (modus == "fatalities") {

  fatalitiesData.selectAll(".fatalitiesData")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.5);

  d3.select("#callOut2").style("visibility","hidden");


  }

  if (modus == "injuries") {

  injuriesData.selectAll(".injuriesData")
    .style("fill-opacity", 0.5);

  d3.select("#callOut3").style("visibility","hidden");


  }


}; 

//totalIncidents 
function totalIncidentsLineGraph() {

modus = "incidents"; 


var margin = {top: 80, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var svg = d3.select("#svg").append("svg")
              .attr("width", width)
              .attr("height", height);

var incidentsData = svg.append("g"); 

incidentsData.selectAll(".incidentsData")
                .data(incidentData)
                .enter()
                .append('incidentsData') 
                .attr('class', 'incidentsData');
                //.on("mouseover", showOne)
                //.on("mouseout", showAll); 
                //.attr('id', function (d) { return "id_2010_" + d.rank_pop; })

//var parse = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;
var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse; 

// Scales and axes. Note the inverted domain for the y-scale: bigger is up!
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-height).tickSubdivide(true),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(4).orient("right");

// An area generator, for the light fill.
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.incidents); }); 

// A line generator, for the dark stroke.
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.incidents); });


// Parse dates and numbers. We assume israel are sorted by date.
function type(d) {
  d.country = d.country;
  d.date = parse(d.date);
  d.incidents = +d.incidents
  return d;
};



var data = d3.csv("static/data/israel/incidents_linechart.csv", type, function(error, data) {
    console.log(data);

  var israel = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.country == "Israel";
  });

  var unitedStates = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.country == "United States";
  });

  var iran = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.country == "Iran";
  });

  var saudiArabia = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.country == "Saudi Arabia";
  });

  var turkey = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.country == "Turkey";
  });

  var egypt = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.country == "Egypt";
  });

  var syria = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.country == "Syria";
  });

  var lebanon = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.country == "Lebanon";
  });

  var jordan = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.country == "Jordan";
  });

  var palestine = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.country == "Palestine";
  });

  x.domain([unitedStates[0].date, unitedStates[unitedStates.length - 1].date]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(egypt, function(d) { return d.incidents; })]).nice();

  //x.domain([israel[0].date, israel[israel.length - 1].date]);
  //y.domain([0, d3.max(israel, function(d) { return d.incidents; })]).nice();

  // Add an SVG element with the desired dimensions and margin.
  var svg = d3.select("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

  // Add the clip path.
  svg.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  // Add the x-axis.
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  // Add the y-axis.
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
      .call(yAxis);


  var colors = d3.scale.category10();

  svg.selectAll('.line')
    .data([israel, unitedStates, iran, saudiArabia, turkey, egypt, syria, lebanon, jordan, palestine]) /// can add however many i want here 
    .enter()
      .append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .style('stroke', function(d) {
          return colors(Math.random() * 50);
        })
        .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          return line(d);
        })
      .on("mouseover", showOne)
      .on("mouseout", showAll); 


  /* Add 'curtain' rectangle to hide entire graph */
  var curtain = svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', -1 * width)
    .attr('y', -1 * height)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('class', 'curtain')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(180)')
    .style('fill', '#ffffff')

  /* Optionally add a guideline */
  var guideline = svg.append('line')
    .attr('stroke', '#333')
    .attr('stroke-width', 0)
    .attr('class', 'guide')
    .attr('x1', 1)
    .attr('y1', 1)
    .attr('x2', 1)
    .attr('y2', height)

  /* Create a shared transition for anything we're animating */
  var t = svg.transition()
    .delay(750)
    .duration(6000)
    .ease('linear')
    .each('end', function() {
      d3.select('line.guide')
        .transition()
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .remove()
    });

  t.select('rect.curtain')
    .attr('width', 0);
  t.select('line.guide')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 0)')

  d3.select("#show_guideline").on("change", function(e) {
    guideline.attr('stroke-width', this.checked ? 1 : 0);
    curtain.attr("opacity", this.checked ? 0.75 : 1);
  })


});

};
```

here is a snippet of my data:

[image: incidentData]

any help owuld be immensely appreciated.

Comment: To help people answer your question, and aid you in understanding your own problem more thoroughly, please present your question as a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Reduce your code to the smallest piece that illustrates the problem. We don't need to see the code that draws the graph, we just need to see the part that reads the data and logs it to the console. In doing this, you will likely discover the problem yourself, but at least someone else can understand your problem quickly. Also, don't show your data as an image, just post it as text.

Comment: you can copy your source code but are unable to copy a section of the data? Have a look at `d3.nest`